# Isotope NextGen Gallery template thumbnails cut-off and overlapping

Tags: css, wordpress, templates, jquery-isotope, nextgen-gallery

I've implemented a NextGen custom template (found here: https://github.com/cevenson/isotope-nextgen-gallery-template) for a client's WP site, but my thumbnails appear to cut-off and overlap on [most of] the initial load of the page (see screenshot below).

Also, the tag filtering doesn't actually work for all of the 'categories'. They're all coded the same in the filtering menu, so I'm not sure what could be wrong with the ones that don't work.

The site I'm using this on is: http://rajbhavsar.com/photos

Anyone use this? Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: screenshot of isotope thumbnail problem]

**EDIT:**

The template code I'm using is as follows. Nothing looked out of the ordinary or problematic. Hence why I'm posting on here.

```
<?php 
/**
Template Page for the gallery overview

Follow variables are useable :

$gallery     : Contain all about the gallery
$images      : Contain all images, path, title
$pagination  : Contain the pagination content

You can check the content when you insert the tag <?php var_dump($variable) ?>
If you would like to show the timestamp of the image ,you can use <?php echo $exif['created_timestamp'] ?>
**/
?>

<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.isotope.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">

/**** centre nav and put at bottom ****/
.ngg-navigation{
position: relative;
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#isotopegallery{
clear: both;
margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

/**** Isotope Filtering ****/

.isotope-item {
    z-index: 2;
}

.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
pointer-events: none;
z-index: 1;
}

/**** Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/

.isotope, .isotope .isotope-item {
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope {
-webkit-transition-property: height, width;
-moz-transition-property: height, width;
-ms-transition-property: height, width;
-o-transition-property: height, width;
transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
-moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
-ms-transition-property:     -ms-transform, opacity;
-o-transition-property:         top, left, opacity;
transition-property:         transform, opacity;
}

/**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/

.isotope.no-transition,
.isotope.no-transition .isotope-item,
.isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
-webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0s;
-ms-transition-duration: 0s;
-o-transition-duration: 0s;
transition-duration: 0s;
}

.photo{
float:left;
margin:0 10px 10px 0;
}

#filters{
margin-left:0;
border: none;
}

#filters li{
display: block;
float:left;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#filters li a{
background: #242424;
padding:8px;
margin:5px 6px 5px 0;
color:#878787;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:normal; 
}

#filters li a:hover{
background: #595959;
}

</style>

<script>
jQuery(function($){

var $container = $('#isotopegallery');

$container.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.photo'
});

$('#filters a').click(function(){
var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$container.isotope({ filter: selector });
return false;
});
});
</script>



<ul id="filters" class="clearfix">
<li><a href="#" data-filter="*">Show All</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".acting">Acting</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".cirque">Cirque</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".film">Film</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".gymnastics">Gymnastics</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".live-events">Live Events</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".people">people</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".portrait">Portrait</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".quotes">Quotes</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".speaking">Speaking</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".television">Television</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".travel">Travel</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".uncategorized">Uncategorized</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".usa-yoga">USA Yoga</a></li>
</ul>


<?php if (!defined ('ABSPATH')) die ('No direct access allowed'); ?><?php if (!empty ($gallery)) : ?>

<div id="isotopegallery" class="photos clearfix" id="<?php echo $gallery->anchor ?>">

    <?php
            //Used to break down and extract the width and height of each image
            function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
                    $string = " ".$string;
                    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
                    if ($ini == 0) return "";
                    $ini += strlen($start);
                    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
                    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
            }
    ?>

    <!-- Thumbnails -->
    <?php foreach ( $images as $image ) : ?>


            <?php if ( !$image->hidden ) {
                    //GET the Size parameters for each image. this i used to size the div box that the images go inside of.
                    $the_size_string = $image->size;
                    $thewidth = get_string_between($the_size_string, "width=\"", "\"");
                    $theheight = get_string_between($the_size_string, "height=\"", "\"");
                    $divstyle = 'width:'.$thewidth.'px; height:'.$theheight.'px;'; 
            }?>


                    <?php
                            //Get the TAGS for this image  
                            $tags = wp_get_object_terms($image->pid,'ngg_tag');
                            $tag_string = ''; //store the list of strings to be put into the class menu for isotpe filtering       
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ( $tags as $tag ) : ?>     
                              <?php $tag_string = $tag_string.$tag->slug.' ';  //alternativley can use $tag->name;, slug with put hyphen between words ?>      
                            <?php endforeach; ?>   

            <div class="photo <?php echo $tag_string ?>" style="<?php echo $divstyle; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $image->imageURL ?>" title="<?php echo $image->description ?>" <?php echo $image->thumbcode ?> >
                            <?php if ( !$image->hidden ) { ?>
                            <img title="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>" />
                            <?php } ?>
                    </a>
            </div> 

            <?php if ( $image->hidden ) continue; ?>
            <?php if ( $gallery->columns > 0 && ++$i % $gallery->columns == 0 ) { ?>
                    <br style="clear: both" />
            <?php } ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>

<!-- Pagination -->
    <?php echo $pagination ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You should supply some code, or something that shows youve put in some effort into diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Added my template code. I hadn't seen anything out of the ordinary there, and everything else can be viewed in the source of the url I posted. Hence why I posted.

Comment: I am not able to replicate the error picture above, the website shows up correct for me, have you modified your code to fix the error? Deleting my cache gives me the 'error' you listed above, but it seems more like a feature, after a second on the page they exploded out to the proper format.

Comment: It's still happening for me, particularly when I refresh (⌘R) the page a time or two. Maybe just a glitch in jQuery when it's reading the initial size of the containing div? And once it figures it out, they spread out?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( window ).load(function( $ ) {
```

It's not working on load, it's working on resize or refresh, right? It might help to load the CSS BEFORE the call to isotope.min.js and why don't you stick the initialization in there too.

```
<ul id="filters" class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">Show All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".acting">Acting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".cirque">Cirque</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".film">Film</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".gymnastics">Gymnastics</a></li>
     ...
```

These filters do not precisely mirror the classes. You have a class "cirque-3" but your filter is only .cirque and so on. All if not most of them don't match.

Comment: Thanks! Moving the isotope call after the CSS helped. I'm still getting something similar to the original problem on "Page 2" of the images (screenshot here: [link](http://i.imgur.com/B5HDpE0.png)). Any ideas?    Also, I realized I had a problem with the tag sorting when I saw the duplicate tag slugs ("cirque-3") as well. Now I'm figuring out how to modify the NextGen Gallery tag slugs, so thanks for that.

Comment: Isotope works by loading the .item on the screen so that it can get a height, the page 2 is hidden but loaded so it's not going to draw properly. I don't know what to do to fix this, but the thing is to load it and then hide it, not load while hiding. You can check around to see if there's help for it.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Also, and this is an amateur question, but the first bit of code you suggested: `jQuery(window).load(function () {` doesn't work in place of the original `jQuery(function($){`. I get a console error of: _TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating '$('#isotopegallery')')_.

Comment: Correction: the error shows with both `jQuery(window).load(function () {` and `jQuery(function($){`

Comment: jQuery(window).load(function ($) {

Comment: I forgot the $ in there.

Comment: Right right. Thanks for all your help. I'm still getting the following error: _TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#isotopegallery')')_. Any thoughts?

Comment: Send link. Also, what version of jQuery?

Comment: The page in question is here: [link](http://rajbhavsar.com/photos/). Checking the `<head>`, I see version _1.10.2_ pulled from the "Use Google Libraries" plugin I'm using.

Comment: $.noConflict();
jQuery( window ).load(function( $ ) {

Comment: Hm, now I get this error: _TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.noConflict')_. I believe Wordpress already runs jQuery in "no conflict" mode, so shouldn't using _jQuery_ instead of _$_ infer the no conflict mode? I really do appreciate you looking into all this. Javascript/jQuery is not my forté, though I'd love to learn.

Comment: Mm, I'm afraid neither worked. Still getting that same error.

Comment: Gonna have to close this out, try asking a question separately. Also, try the Wordpress forums. Never had an issue with this before.